# Are Bernoulli distributions R-sub-Gaussian?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

A distribution $\nu$ is said to be *R-sub-Gaussian*, $R>0$, if for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\nu}\left[\exp(tX-t\mathbb{E}(X))\right]\le\exp(R^2t^2/2)
\end{align}
Is it possible to write a Bernoulli distribution with mean $p$ as an R-sub-Gaussian distribution for some $R$?

Comment: All bounded variables are subgaussian. See [Example 2.3 here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially the content of [Hoeffding's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma), which states that a random variable supported on the interval $[a,b]$ is sub-Gaussian with $R = (b-a)/2$. So Bernoulli random variables are sub-Gaussian with $R=1/2$.

Comment: Doesn't Hoeffding's lemma assume that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand your description now after reading this: http://blog.wouterkoolen.info/BernoulliSubGaussian/post.html

Comment: @jonem Apply Hoeffding's lemma to the random variable $Y := X - E[X]$.